# Issue with function having aggregate function (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle11g

**This is with regards ORACLE**

I have one function which will return me some xml value, but whenever there is any aggregate function (like in current function it's COUNT()) it gives me an error like,

```
ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY
```

Suggest me what is the solution for this ???

Following is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funxmlresultAGGTest (abc varchar2)
RETURN CLOB
AS
   my_xml   CLOB;
BEGIN
   SELECT XMLELEMENT ("DATASET",
                      XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT ("ROW",
                                          XMLFOREST (COUNT (*) AS count1)
                                         )
                             )
                     ).getclobval ()
     INTO my_xml
     FROM pam_tab;

   RETURN my_xml;
END;
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only a single column I would suggest the following change:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT (
         "DATASET",
         XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT ("ROW", XMLFOREST (COUNT ( * ) AS count1)))
     ).getclobval ()
INTO my_xml
FROM pam_tab
GROUP BY 1;
```